# Automatically reloading new classes in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I wrote this simple code

```
package com.abhi;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration

public class HelloWorldController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    String getMessage() {
        return "<h1>Hello World</h1>";
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldController.class, args);
    }
}
```

I am compiling and running this using Gradle (Inside IntelliJ Idea).

```
group 'com.abhi'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "com.abhi.HelloWorldController"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.3.0.RELEASE'
}
```

Now when I run this in intellij and access it at http://localhost:8080. it works fine. but if I change the string to Hello World New and recompile... the browser still shows old "Hello World" on refresh.

so is there a way in which I can change the string and recompile and my changes are picked up instantaneously without restarting the web server?

Answer (score 2):

As of Spring Boot 1.3.0, [Developer tools offer a live reload feature](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html) (and more!).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [JRebel](https://my.jrebel.com/) to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Spring Loaded. Check out the following links:

[Spring Hot-Swapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html)

[Github Spring Loaded](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded)